# ffmpeg throws error while converting wav to flac

Tags: ffmpeg, wav, flac

I am working on a research project and it requires me to first record audios from browser (using getuserMedia) and save them in a wav format. My code looks like this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
        const chunks = [];
        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
            chunks.push(e.data);
            if (recorder.state == 'inactive') {
                $scope.blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                $scope.file = new File([$scope.blob], "myFile.wav", {type: 'audio/wav', lastModified: Date.now()});

                $scope.blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL($scope.blob);
                createAudioElement($scope.blobUrl);
            }
        };
        recorder.start(1000);
        $scope.stop = function() {
            recorder.stop();    
        };

    }).catch(console.error);
```

After saving $scope.file on filesystem, I convert it to flac format using ffmpeg utility ([https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Now my problem is the ffmpeg tool sometimes gives me error saying that this file cannot be recognized as wav file. The exact output of ffmpeg tool is:

```
  ffmpeg-user: Wav to Flac conversion: Invalid data found when processing input

  ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers 
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81) 
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared 
  --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 
  --enable-hardcoded-tables 
  --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= 
  --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl 

  --disable-lzma --enable-vda 
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100 
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100 
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100 
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100 
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100 
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0 
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100 
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100 
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
```

Does anyone know why am I getting this error?

Comment: I see no `ffmpeg` error. This question reminds me of [ffmpeg-user: Wav to Flac conversion: Invalid data found when processing input](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-August/037009.html).

Comment: That's me @LordNeckbeard. Couldn't make it work over there. Struggling  since last week. Let me update the question so that you can see the actual error.